# Cannot find overload for ExecuteBatch error in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage, azure-rm, az

I am doing batch uploads from a csv file to Azure table storage through a Powershell script and i have a command:  $table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation) 
for which i'm getting the error mentioned in the header of the question of my post. I believe that "ExecuteBatch" is a method in the old AzureRm module and not the newer Az module which i am using, which is causing it to break. Is there a corresponding method in Az module for "ExecuteBatch"?

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, if we use new Azure PowerShell module Az to manage Azure Table storage, we need to use the SDK `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`. 
[image]

So if ou want to use `ExecuteBatch` method, we need to use the command `[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation] $batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation` to create TableBatchOperation. For example:

```
Connect-AzAccount

$ResourceGroupName = "testfun06"
$StorageAccountName="testfun06bf01"
$TableName="People"

$keys=Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName  -StorageAccountKey $keys[0].Value
$table = Get-AzStorageTable  -Name $TableName -Context $ctx

$e = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity("Jim","test")
$e1 = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity("Jim","test1")
[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation] $batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation
$batchOperation.InsertOrMerge($e)
$batchOperation.InsertOrMerge($e1)

$table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)
```

[image]