# Batch insert into Azure Table Storage using Power Shell

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage

Is there something similar to the AzureTableEntity module that can be used to insert batches of data in an Azure Table Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will help you in executing the batch insert operation

```php
Connect-AzAccount

$ResourceGroupName = "testfun06"
$StorageAccountName="testfun06bf01"
$TableName="People"

$keys=Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName  -StorageAccountKey $keys[0].Value
$table = Get-AzStorageTable  -Name $TableName -Context $ctx

$e = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity("Jim","test")
$e1 = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity("Jim","test1")
[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation] $batchOperation = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableBatchOperation
$batchOperation.InsertOrMerge($e)
$batchOperation.InsertOrMerge($e1)

$table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)
```

[image]

For further information check the [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57949760) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450142) threads.